# If $P(A) = 0.6$, $P(B) = .55$ and $P(A\cap B) = 0.2$, find the probability of $P(A\cap B')$.

Tags: probability

Would the answer be $0.27$? The probability of $B'$ is $0.45$, so I think we would multiply $0.6\cdot 0.45$, giving us $0.27$. If not, can someone explain how to do this problem?

Comment: $P(A) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap B')$.

Comment: "*So I think we would multiply...*"  You can only multiply two probabilities like this if you know ahead of time that they are independent events.  $\Pr(A\cap B)$ is **not** equal to $Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$ under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

The key is that $A\cap B$ and $A\cap B'$ are complementary events. Take event $A$ as given; then we have two scenarios: either $B$ also occurs or it does not. You can think of each compound event as representing part of the probability that $A$ occurs. Since $A\cap B$ and $A\cap B'$ are mutually exclusive events (we can't have both $B$ and $B'$ happening, after all) and each of these events represent a part of $P(A)$, it must be that $P(A)$ is given by their sum. That is, $P(A) = P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B')$. Rearranging for $P(A\cap B')$ yields $P(A\cap B') = P(A)-P(A\cap B)$, and substituting the given values gives $P(A\cap B') = 0.6-0.2 = 0.4$.

Comment: What is the point of repeating the analysis given in the comment of peterwhy, immediately following the posted question?  Before leaving this comment, I compared the time stamps of your response and peterwhy's response.

Comment: @user2661923 Because the question needed an answer and peterwhy hadn't made his comment into one? Not to mention that a bare statement of the formula is _not_ an analysis in itself, so I actually didn't copy anything. Why does this offend you?

Comment: No, the question did not deserve an answer, because the OP (i.e. original poster) had not really shown any work.  Peterwhy's response was intended to influence the OP to do his own work on the problem, which seems appropriate, given the defects in the posting.  See also [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: @user2661923 jesus christ, mate. Could you possibly be any more officious?... I saw a question without an answer, the OP had made an attempt to answer it themselves (even if weakly), so I thought I'd throw them a bone and explain the logic behind the answer. If you find that unforgivable then report me or something; either way, I've had enough of this unlooked-for argument

Comment: Sorry I just noticed these comments mention @peterwhy, and I support this answer.

Comment: @peterwhy thank you for the support my friend :) I am genuinely sorry if I actually subverted the intent of your comment as hypothesized by the other user